# What should I do if I answer my own question I put a bounty on?

Tags: support, bounty

I eventually solved my own problem after I put up a bounty and now don't know what to do to cancel it or give it to myself.

Here's the post: [How can I initiate a modem connection from the command line?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21573/how-can-i-initiate-a-modem-connection-from-the-command-line/23691#23691)

Answer (score 1):

Ask, but typically not through here, instead just flag it for moderation.

I have removed the bounty and it got automagically refunded to you.